# multiarch reposync on redhat

Tags: linux, redhat, repository

Question here about downloading RH repos.  I currently have a licensed Redhat 32 bit system.  It automatically pulls from the RHN 32 bit repo using reposync.  However, I am trying to also pull 64 bit repository on the same system.  I do not want to burden myself by adding an extra 64 bit system.  No matter what I try RH is giving me:

*This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/5Server/en/os/x86_64/Debuginfo/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 4] IOError: [Errno ftp error] timed out
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: rhel-debuginfo64. Please verify its path and try again*

This is after I took the 32 bit repo in /etc/yum.repos.d/* and added a new repo by modifying the old address and adding the "x86_64" as seen from the above error.

To make things a bit more clear... I'm not trying to update my 32bit system with 64 bit RH packages.  I'm simply trying to reposync or download just the 32bit and 64bit RH repositories on my 32 bit system.

Does anyone have advice on doing reposync on both 32 bit and 64 bit RH repositories on a single RH system?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [mrepo](https://github.com/dagwieers/mrepo).

RedHat allows machines to subscribe to only one channel (and its child channels) on RHN, which means you can't get updates for different architectures/OS versions from a single machine. To circumvent this, you can create "fake" machine identities with gensystemid (included in mrepo) then use rhnget (also included in mrepo) with the generated identities to fetch content from multipe channels. Details about the procedure can be found [here](https://github.com/dagwieers/mrepo/blob/master/docs/redhat-network.txt).